# how to get two dimensional string Array from one Activity to other

Tags: android, android-activity, multidimensional-array

I am new to Android. Please tell me how to get two dimensional  string Array from one Activity to other Activity.
 Thank You

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can give you the simplest answer, Make a Serializable Class for getter and setter and use your data anywhere in your application as:

```
Class ABC implements Serializable
{
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
   String[][] str;
   private static ABC singletonObject;
    public static ABC getSingletonObject() {
        if (singletonObject == null) {
            singletonObject = new ABC ();
        }
        return singletonObject;
    }
   public void setString(String[][] str)
   {
      this.str = str;
   }
   public String[][] getString()
   {
      return str;
   }
}
```

---

Yous can set it as

```
ABC s = ABC.getSingletonObject();
s.setString(str);
```

---

In another activity

```
ABC s = ABC.getSingletonObject();
String[][] str = s.GetString();
```

---

and enjoy

Answer (score 6):

You can use `Android` `Parcelable` Class for passing `Serializable` data like `Arrays`. Below is the Example in your case.

```
public class MyParcelable implements Parcelable{

    public String[][] strings;

    public String[][] getStrings() {
        return strings;
    }

    public void setStrings(String[][] strings) {
        this.strings = strings;
    }

    public MyParcelable() {
        strings = new String[1][1];
    }

    public MyParcelable(Parcel in) {
        strings = (String[][]) in.readSerializable();
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeSerializable(strings);

    }
    public static final Parcelable.Creator<MyParcelable> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<MyParcelable>() {

        @Override
        public MyParcelable createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new MyParcelable(in);
        }

        @Override
        public MyParcelable[] newArray(int size) {
            return new MyParcelable[size];
        }
    };
}
```

To pass to Another Activity -

```
public String[][] strings = new String[1][1];
strings[0][0] = "data";

MyParcelable myParcelable = new MyParcelable();
myParcelable.setStrings(strings);
intent.putExtra("parcel",myParcelable);
startActivity(intent);
```

To Retrieve -

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Bundle b = intent.getExtras();
MyParcelable myParcelable = b.getParcelable("parcel");
strings = myParcelable.getStrings();
Log.d("Your String[0][0] is - ",strings[0][0]+"");
```

Output -

```
12-29 12:49:39.016: D/Your String[0][0] is -(1484): data
```

Comment: I got Exception   "java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object;"

Comment: Sorry to reply late, You can also use Androids Parcelable Class for Serializable of your data.

Answer (score 1):

easiest way is to wrap it in a serializable class and pass it in the intent :)

Answer (score 0):

You could do it row by row. Not elegant or efficient. But if you had a i by j array, you could send i arrays of length j on their own and then in the new activity put them back together.

Assuming i and j are pretty small that is.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways. 1) Keep it in a static variable accessible accross activites 2) Make it as serializable data and put it in bundle.

Comment: please give some sample code for this two ways

Answer (score 0):

You can use putSerializable to set set bytearray and use getSerializable to retrive
Have a look on the following approach

Create a serializable class assign the String array and put that serializable in intent

**Step-1**    Create a Serializable Bean Class to set the array to the class

```
public class MyBean implements Serializable{
    String[][] data = null;
    public void set2DArray(String[][] data){
        this.data = data;
    }
    public String[][] get2DArray(){
        return data;
    }
}
```

**Step-2 in Caller Activity (Home class)**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Second.class);

        String data[][] = new String[][] {{"1","pavan"},{"2","kumar"},{"3","kora"},{"1","pavan"},{"2","kumar"},{"3","kora333"}};
        MyBean bean = new MyBean();
        bean.set2DArray(data);
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putSerializable("mybean", bean);
        i.putExtra("obj", b);
        startActivity(i);
```

**Step-3 In Calling Activity (Second class)**

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getBundleExtra("obj");
       MyBean dData = (MyBean) b.getSerializable("mybean");
       String[][] str =dData.get2DArray();
```