# how to pass 2D Array as a parameter to another Activity?

Tags: android

how to pass 2D Array as a parameter to another Activity?? i try it stack over flow solution but is not work  im using this code 
 in activity 1 is correctly show value in  this line  bundle.putSerializable("xmlResponee", xmlRespone);
but is not showe value in  activity2 class  what is wrong? tell me please

```
public class Activity1 extends Activity {

  private String[][] xmlRespone;
  Intent i = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), Activity2.class);
  Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
  bundle.putSerializable("xmlResponee", xmlRespone);
  i.putExtras(bundle);
  startActivity(i);
```

and

```
public class Activity2 extends Activity {

   private String[][] xmlRespone;
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {                
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity2);
      Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

      String[][] xmlRespone2 = (String[][]) bundle.getSerializable("xmlResponee");
```

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/8664640/760489

Comment: @smart guy did you check Pratik's link.i think it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a static class.. with private String[][] xmlRespone. in first Activity you can Assign value to it,and in another activity you can call data from it..

Activity A ---> Static class X ---> Activity B.

Comment: u mean make 3rd class? how i set without use another clas just pass value to 2nd activity?

Comment: please help me how i get 2D string in another acitivity

Comment: i get answer by using this example
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8664370/how-to-get-two-dimensional-string-array-from-one-activity-to-other/8664640#8664640

Answer (score 0):

Hey just use `Parcelable` objects to pass objects between android activities.

Here is a really awesome [example](http://blog.cluepusher.dk/2009/10/28/writing-parcelable-classes-for-android/). I guess this is the same thing you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You can put it directly on the intent no need bundle.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra("MyXML", xmlRespone);
```

And to read:

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String[] xmlRespone = intent.getStringArrayExtra("MyXML");
    }
```