# Passing 2d String array to new Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, multidimensional-array, android-activity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to get two dimensional string Array from one Activity to other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8664370/how-to-get-two-dimensional-string-array-from-one-activity-to-other)

I have a 2d String array something like this

```
String[][] ContactList = new String[][]
        {
        { "a", 123 },
        { "b", 123 },
        { "c", 123 },
        { "d", 123 } };
```

How to pass this array to another activity???

and then in that activity, how can I retrieve this array???

Comment: looks more like a map than like a 2d string array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create one bundle in bundle put parceable array list provided by labeeb and set to intent here is the code for

```
Intent i = new Intent(this,name.class);
 Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putIntegerArrayListExtra(String name, ArrayList<Integer> value);
//b.putParcelableArrayListExtra(String name, ArrayList<? extends Parcelable> value);
//b.putStringArrayListExtra(String name, ArrayList<String> value);
i.putExtra(String name,b);
startActivity(i);
```

And get data into another activity like

```
//pseudo code
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtra().putParcelableArrayListExtra(String name);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `Bundle`:

```
bundleInstance.putSerializable("ContactList ", ContactList);
```

To retrive it:

```
String[][] ContactList = (String[][]) bundleInstance.getSerializable("ContactList ");
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually serialize it as a simple string object such as "a:123;b:123;c:123;d:123" and unserialize it in the other activity. Depends on the number of row you have but it is a quick and easy way to pass it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(/* ... */);

int i = 0;
for (String[] arr : contactList) {
  intent.putExtra("StringArray#" + i, arr);
  ++i;
}
intent.putExtra("StringArrayCount", i);
```

In the other activity, you would start by reading the count and then each "StringArray#" property using `getStringArrayExtra`.

Answer (score 0):

in this case why not using Hashmap and ArrayList??

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>
```

and then using put for adding data and using get for getting it